# Static constexpr reference or static constexpr object in header file

Tags: c++, static, one-definition-rule

Inside the standardization paper [ABI for std::hardware_{constructive,destructive}_interference_size](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2018/p1119r0.html) it is proposed to declare hardware interference sizes as static reference in order to mitigate some ODR violation risks.

```
static constexpr const std::size_t& hardware_destructive_interference_size = implementation-defined;
static constexpr const std::size_t& hardware_constructive_interference_size = implementation-defined;
```

I wonder why declaring these variables as reference is a better choice than just const object as in:

```
static constexpr std::size_t hardware_destructive_interference_size = implementation-defined;
static constexpr std::size_t hardware_constructive_interference_size = implementation-defined;
```

Comment: The authors want the values to both be known at compile time, and not known until link time. So they chase their own tails, so to speak.